# Ant rpm build fails due to unknown option '-bs'

Tags: ant, instantiation, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, antbuilder

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="main" basedir=".">
<echo message="pulling in property files" />
<property file="axis_bujava.properties" />

<echo message="calling the RPM Build Ant" />
<target name="main">
    <rpm specfile="example.spec" topdir="${basedir}" command="-bs" />
</target>
</project>
```

example.spec

```
Summary: xxx

Name: cdplayer

Version: 1.0

Release: 1

Copyright: xxx

Group: Applications/Sound

Source: xxx.tgz

URL: http://xxx.html

Distribution: xxxx

Vendor:xxx.

Packager: xxx

%description
xxxx
%build
make
%install
make install
```

output:

```
Buildfile: /home/user1/workspace/antdemo/build.xml
     [echo] pulling in property files

     [echo] calling the RPM Build Ant

main:

      [rpm] Building the RPM based on the example.spec file

      [rpm] -bs: unknown option

      [rpm] 'rpm' failed with exit code 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 848 milliseconds
```

Comment: Sounds like it is sending it to the `rpm` executable instead of `rpmbuild`?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue too.  In my case the OS did not have the 'rpmbuild' command installed, so the ant task was calling 'rpm' instead as Aaron suggested.

Comment: yum install rpm-build will install the required rpm.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what "-bs" option is, you might try changing it to "-bb", which is the default. My own builds, plus a few I've seen, usually use -bb (http://richardfriedman.blogspot.com/2007/02/rpm-java-and-frustration.html)

Also see: 
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rpm.html